# TypeScript error in queryFn when using Supabase authentication with React Toolkit Query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, rtk-query, supabase-js

I have been trying to use Supabase authentication with [React Toolkit Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) but I have been getting an issue in using the `queryFn`.

Below is the code which uses the `supabase.auth.signUp` to sign up a user using email/password. The docs for the below function are found [here](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signinwithpassword).

```
interface SignupResponse {
  data?: any;
  error?: {
    message: string;
    status: number;
  };
}

signupWithCredentials: builder.mutation<SignupResponse, Signup>({
  async queryFn({ email, password }) {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email,
      password,
    });

    //workaround to check if the email address is already in use.
    if (data?.user?.identities?.length === 0) {
      return {
        error: {
          message: "Email already registered",
          status: 500,
        },
      };
    }

    //if the error is not null, return back the message
    if (error !== null) {
      return {
        error: {
          message: error.message,
          status: error.status,
        },
      };
    }

    // if all validations pass, return back the user
    return { data };
  },
}),
```

For reference, `Signup` is defined like below,

```
const SignupForm = z.object({
  email: z.string().email({ message: "Please enter a valid email address." }),
  password: z
    .string()
    .min(6, { message: "Minimum 2 characters." })
    .max(50, { message: "Minimum 2 characters." }),
  confirmPassword: z.string().min(2).max(50),
  name: z.string().min(2, { message: "Name must be at least 2 characters." }),
});

type Signup = z.infer<typeof SignupApi>;
```

In a nutshell, `signupWithCredentials` is a mutation which would register a user using email/password in the Supabase database. However, I have been getting the following error on the `queryFn` which I am unable to resolve,

```
Type '({ email, password }: { email: string; password: string; }) => Promise<{ error: { message: string; status: number | undefined; }; data?: undefined; } | { data: { user: User | null; session: Session | null; }; error?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type '(arg: { email: string; password: string; }, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}, baseQuery: (arg: any) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, unknown, {}>>) => MaybePromise<...>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ error: { message: string; status: number | undefined; }; data?: undefined; } | { data: { user: User | null; session: Session | null; }; error?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<SignupResponse, unknown>>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ error: { message: string; status: number | undefined; }; data?: undefined; } | { data: { user: User | null; session: Session | null; }; error?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<QueryReturnValue<SignupResponse, unknown>>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '<TResult1 = { error: { message: string; status: number | undefined; }; data?: undefined; } | { data: { user: User | null; session: Session | null; }; error?: undefined; }, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: { ...; } | { ...; }) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => ...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = QueryReturnValue<SignupResponse, unknown>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: QueryReturnValue<SignupResponse, unknown>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type '{ error: { message: string; status: number | undefined; }; data?: undefined; } | { data: { user: User | null; session: Session | null; }; error?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'QueryReturnValue<SignupResponse, unknown>'.
                Type '{ data: { user: User | null; session: Session | null; }; error?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'QueryReturnValue<SignupResponse, unknown>'.
                  Type '{ data: { user: User | null; session: Session | null; }; error?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ error?: undefined; data: SignupResponse; meta?: unknown; }'.
                    Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
                      Type '{ user: User | null; session: Session | null; }' has no properties in common with type 'SignupResponse'.ts(2322)
```

I am honestly not sure of what this error is trying to say.

If required, I have created a working sample of this code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/beautiful-stitch-5slx93). Any help would be appreciated.

I even tried updating the mutation return type to `AuthResponse` instead of the interface `SignupResponse`, but it works only for a return of an `error` and not for `data`. See example below,

```
      signupWithCredentials: builder.mutation<AuthResponse, Signup>({ 
        async queryFn({ email, password }) {
          const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
            email,
            password,
          });

          if (error) {
            return { error };
          }

          // below return causes an error
          return { data };
        },
      }),
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [RTK Query docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#typing-a-queryfn), your returned error should be in the following format if you're using `fetchBaseQuery`:

```js
return {
  error: {
    status: 500,
    statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
    data: 'Invalid ID provided.',
  },
}
```

But the error you're returning is in a different format. If you only use `queryFn` for all the endpoints, you can also use `fakeBaseQuery` with a custom error type like so:

```
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'

type CustomErrorType = { message: string, status: number }

const api = createApi({
  // This type will be used as the error type for all `queryFn` functions provided
  //                              v
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery<CustomErrorType>(),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    signupWithCredentials: builder.mutation<SignupResponse, Signup>({
      async queryFn({ email, password }) {
        const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
          email,
          password,
        });

        //workaround to check if the email address is already in use.
        if (data?.user?.identities?.length === 0) {
          return {
            error: {
              message: "Email already registered",
              status: 500,
            },
          };
        }

        //if the error is not null, return back the message
        if (error !== null) {
          return {
            error: {
              message: error.message,
              status: error.status,
            },
          };
        }

        // if all validations pass, return back the user
        return { data };
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

You also need to properly type the `SignupResponse` interface to what the type of `data` returned from supabase is. `SignupResponse` should not have the error type in it. So:

```
interface SignupResponse {
  data?: any; //Proper type should be used if possible
}
```